# Flexbox sometimes does not work and suddenly works again

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use Flexbox with space-between to get a result on the right side of the website and the table on the left side. It works perfectly fine, until I press a button. I colored the flexitems to see what exactly happens, but the colors just dissappear and suddenly the Result is under the table no matter the size of the table.

Sometimes when I pressed the button the flexbox works again after I opened the style.css file. The width of the table is always kinda the Same, only the length of the Name might stretch it a bit but it is never as wide as the screen so that the flexitem with the result would need to be under the table.

Also the Result is in a colored  and is just as wide as the text which isnt much, but when I pressed the button the  suddenly is as wide as the screen.

I tried: `flex-wrap: nowrap`, fixed width and height, `flex: 1 1 auto`, `flex: 0 1 auto`, `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `max-height`, `display: inline-flex`, `justify-content: space-around`.

The flexbox I mean is `#phoneTableArticle`

I couldn't find anything wether javascript code could block css. The Table is reinstated when I click the Button, so maybe that is the problem? But I don't know how to solve the problem then.

```css
/*telefonliste.php*/


/*header*/

#headerT {
  display: flex;
}

#selectionHead {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#filter {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/*tabelle und anzeige*/

#phoneTableArticle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#boxItem1 {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

#boxItem2 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#phoneTable {
  margin-top: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*text-shadow: 2px 3px 1px red,  2px -3px 1px blue;*/
}

tbody {
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

#phoneTable td {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#zeitBereich {
  margin-top: 2em;
}


/*adminbereich.php*/

#adminLogin {
  margin-left: 65%;
}

#upload {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#logout {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#file {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#passChange {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section>
    <article id="selectionHead">
      <div id="flexitem1">

        <form method="post">
          <select id="phoneSelect" name="phoneSelect">
            <option value="Alle" selected>Alle</option>

            <!--Fill dropdown with php-->
          </select>
          <!-- Whenever I press this button  -->
          <input id="filter" type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter anwenden">
        </form>


      </div>

      <!--Datepicker-->
      <div id="flexitem2">
        <p>Anfangsdatum: <input type="text" id="startDatepicker"> Enddatum: <input type="text" id="endDatepicker"></p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--  Flexbox   -->
    <article id="phoneTableArticle">

      <!-- Flexitem containting table -->
      <div id="boxItem1">
        <table id="phoneTable">

          <theader>
            <th>Typ </th>
            <th>Datum/Uhrzeit</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rufnummer</th>
            <th>Dauer</th>
          </theader>

          <tbody>
            <!--Fill the TD with php and data from a DB-->

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>

      <!-- Flexitem containting result and a button for calculations -->
      <div id="boxItem2">
        <div class="alert alert-success" id="zeitBereich">
          Die Gesamtdauer beträgt : 00:00:00
        </div>

        <form method="post">
          <input id="gesamtZeit" type="button" onclick="addTimes()" value="Gesamtzeit berechnen">
        </form>
      </div>
    </article>



  </section>

</div>
```

[Before clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1ooK.png)

[Right after I click the Filter button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuwM2.png)

[When I change the CSS (in this case pressed space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AorNl.png)

Thanks everyone.

edit: it does work perfectly fine in firefox and safari. Only in chrome the flexbox disappears whenever I click the filter button. And the Flexbox is only reinstated when I actually change the style.css in any way.

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary code and provide a minimal example showing the actual issue. PHP has nothing to do with flexbox so why include it?

Comment: _“It works perfectly fine, until I press a button”_ - what button are you talking about? Have you checked the HTML output your script produces for errors?

Comment: I hope that all unnecessary code is gone now. I wasnt sure wether or not php could have anything to do with it. 

The button that lets the flexbox for whatever reason is the <input> with the id filter, I commented before it now. 

even if everything is selected and the whole database is basically displayed the flexbox works, until I click the filter button, even if the filter is for all, so it shouldnt happen anything actually.

Comment: Please add your JavaScript, as it apparently changes the markup.

Comment: @Barthy Javascript does not influence the table apparently. I used ddtf.js for Filters but replaced this with my own filter as it only sets display: none to the table rows that are not needed.

Comment: @Pete thanks didnt see this. But it worked before and it didnt change a thing now that I included <tr>

Comment: @bibleblade "The Table is reinstated when I click the Button" sounded like you did that via JS.

So when you click the button the form is submitted and the page reloads, right?  How (and where) do you include your stylesheets? Can you include a screenshot of how it looks like when "the flexbox disappears"?

Comment: @Barthy well when I click the Button a PHP code is run but sven can de scheur suggested that it has nothing to do with the flexbox, why I didnt include it and replaced it with a comment stating where the table is kinda made with php code.

Comment: I know included screenshots, before the click, right after the click and when I changed the css in any way. 
The green div dissappears under the table as I already stated. 

The style.css is included via link in the header.php.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the PHP code indeed blocked the css, somehow. I don't know exactly why it works, but I excluded the PHP code which was where I left the comment, put it in a new file called table.php and then I included this file, where the code once was.

It works perfectly fine now.

Thank you everyone, you help me getting better.

Just to show what I mean here is the before and after code-snippet.

**Before:**

```
<tbody>
                        <!--FÜllen der Tabelle abhängig von der Dropdown auswahl-->
                        <?php 


                            $total = 0;
                            $gesamtDauer = 0;


                            if(isset($_POST['filter'])){


                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


                            if($_POST['phoneSelect'] == 'Alle' && $_POST['nameSelect'] == 'Alle Namen'){

                                 echo "<tr>";
                               if($row['Typ'] == 1){
                                   echo "<td>&#10004;</td>";//Anruf angenommen
                               } 
                                else if($row['Typ'] == 2){
                                    echo "<td>&#10005;</td>";//Anruf abgelehnt
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<td>&#9743;</td>";//Angerufen
                                }

                                    echo "<td>".$row['Datum']."</td>";

                                if($row['Name'] == ''){
                                    echo "<td> Empty </td>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
                                }


                                    echo "<td>0".$row['Rufnummer']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Dauer']."</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";

                            }

                        else if($row['Rufnummer'] == $_POST['phoneSelect']){
                            echo "<tr>";
                               if($row['Typ'] == 1){
                                   echo "<td>&#10004;</td>";//Anruf angenommen
                               } 
                                else if($row['Typ'] == 2){
                                    echo "<td>&#10005;</td>";//Anruf abgelehnt
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<td>&#9743;</td>";//Angerufen
                                }

                                    echo "<td>".$row['Datum']."</td>";

                                if($row['Name'] == ''){
                                    echo "<td> Empty </td>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
                                }


                                    echo "<td>0".$row['Rufnummer']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Dauer']."</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                     }



                        else if($row['Name'] == $_POST['nameSelect']){


                            echo "<tr>";
                               if($row['Typ'] == 1){
                                   echo "<td>&#10004;</td>";//Anruf angenommen
                               } 
                                else if($row['Typ'] == 2){
                                    echo "<td>&#10005;</td>";//Anruf abgelehnt
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<td>&#9743;</td>";//Angerufen
                                }

                                    echo "<td>".$row['Datum']."</td>";

                                if($row['Name'] == ''){
                                    echo "<td> Empty </td>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
                                }


                                    echo "<td>0".$row['Rufnummer']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Dauer']."</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                     }



                                $total += strtotime($row['Dauer']);
                           }  

                        }
//Berechnen der Gesamtdauer beim ersten Aufruf der Webseite
                            $gesamtDauer =  date('d',$total)*24 + date('H',$total).":".date('i', $total).":00";

                            if(isset($_POST['berechnen'])){
                                echo "<div class = 'alert alert-success'> Die Gesamtdauer beträgt : ".$gesamtDauer."</div>";
                            }

                        ?>

                    </tbody>
```

**After:**

```
                <tbody>
                        <!--FÜllen der Tabelle abhängig von der Dropdown auswahl-->
                        <?php 

                        include("table.php");

                        ?>

                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest correcting all `HTML` errors:

- A table header is defined by `<thead>` not `<theader>`
- `<th>` elements must be inside a `<tr>`
- Do not put a `<div>` inside the `<tbody>` as you currently do with the alert

Solving these issues should hopefully resolve your problem for good — moving the php code to a separate file shouldn't really change much.

*Hint: you can use the [w3schools HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to check for errors like these.*

Comment: Thank you for correcting. Brackets for some reason suggested theader so I just pressed enter. 
Corrected tr before but that didnt help. 
There is no div inside the body or table as a whole.

Comment: I couldnt edit my comment that is why I had to comment again. 

edit: sorry now I see what you mean. I already deleted the div as I didn't need it to display the result.